# What are the most frequently accessed sharepoint 2013 databases?

Tags: 2013

Is it safe to assume user profile service application databases and app management service application database are the most frequently accessed SP 2013 database. I also read that these are the only databases that SP WFE's access directly?

Answer (score 4):

It depends on your farm. If you have a hardcore search farm then the usage would slightly turn to the search databases of course.

Go to your SQL Server. Right click on the instance and open your usage report like this:

[image]

[image]